# Launching 'safe' eval()

Tags: python, eval, bots, irc

I m making a irc bot https://github.com/mouuff/MouBot
I would like the bot to reply the `eval()` when the message starts with !math
but its creating failures if the user enter something like !math exit() and stuff like that

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code here. Or if you're really just looking for a simple `eval` without functions, [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.literal_eval) should do the trick.

Comment: "safe eval" - what a wonderful oxymoron... If you've got an IRC bot in a channel with an `eval()` - everyone's going to abuse it - so don't do it... (or at least have some form of access control - (equiv. to owner level on eggdrop) so only people that can already mess things up can do so). If you just want "!math" - then have a look at `pyparsing` and one of its calculator examples, which can parse a string and return a result if necessary

Comment: There is no such thing as a safe eval

Comment: Even if you had a safe eval (in the sense that the user couldn't do anything obviously black-hat), you'd also have to handle the case where someone enters `9**9**9`, which is roughly 4.2812477317574708e+369693099.  Python will happily try to compute all the digits, and there are lots of other DOS attack vectors this way.  You can deal with these if you pay close attention when walking the AST, but it's a headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.

It looks like you are trying to create a math parser. Then use a math parser, not a full-fledged I-will-run-any-code-parser. If you are using *nix, you could use a program like `bc` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) to compile it into an AST, walk the AST making sure that it contains only whitelisted node sets, then execute it.

[Example implementation courtesy of unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236328/20862)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `eval()` is that when it is executed, it is valid python code, and the `exit()` is a valid part of python code, which usually exit's a program (although this specific function should be used in IDLE, and `sys.exit()` is preffered in non-idle use).

For this reason, `eval()` should only be used with trusted input, or you should implement a parser for the commands passed to the `eval()` function, as to elliminate undesirable input (possibly take a look at the `shlex` module for their `split()` function if you wish to implement your own, I have used it for many parsers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple math evaluation why you want to bring whole might of Python behind it, which can and will be abused.

Use something like [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) to write a simple calculator e.g. see [SimpleCalc.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/SimpleCalc.py) or [fournfn.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py) , I think those would be enough to get you started. You can also try [SimpleParse](http://simpleparse.sourceforge.net/)

and if you DO want to provide eval like powerful and abusable feature, you should start a VM, in which start server processes which will reply to eval queries, and also limit each process using [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), when VM goes down start another one or keep a pool of VM and eval processes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it could help you but look at this -> http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html

or this -> [Is there an alternative to rexec for Python sandboxing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525056/is-there-an-alternative-to-rexec-for-python-sandboxing)