# create a relatively safe eval

Tags: python, security, eval

I read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211846/launching-safe-eval) and I'm not convince it applies here.

I have an application where I want to allow mostly preset formulas to be set in widgets: for instance return last part of a string using `str.partition`.

This isn't a webapp but a `wx.widgets` one, only company employees can use it so the risk is minimal, but how could I apply a minimum of security to avoid malignant attacks or simply unaware user errors?

I thought of scanning for `;` so one cannot import a module or pass 2 instructions, and also scan for `os.` and `sys.` (which are already imported in my program so no need to import them to use `os.remove`), and too bad if `os.` or `sys.` are in expressions, that is very unlikely.

Would that be reasonably enough or am I missing a blatant safety/security gap?

Comment: The problem is one could write `"__import__(chr(111)+'s').system('clear')"`. So you hide `os`...

Comment: good remark. I'll search for `__import__` too then.

Comment: I think [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) article explains that it is *near* to impossible (or perhaps even fundamentally impossible) to completely shield `eval(..)`.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236328/67579) can be an initial step to make `eval(..)` more safe.

Comment: thanks for all those comments. Maybe my question is a duplicate of the answer quoted above. I could just allow string manipulations for instance (the only thing I need)

Comment: If it's internal then why check for attacks at all? If you feel you can't trust people, then don't half-ass it. Either avoid all attacks using some sort of DSL or let it be.